# Applying digital signatures (including public/private keys) on a PDF

Tags: ios, pdf-generation, digital-signature

I need to generate PDF in my app (which has been done), and then, mark it with a digital signature for security purposes(which still needs to be taken care of).

Here, I am not talking about simply pasting an image (containing signature) in the pdf file; but actually use public-key/private-key for this purpose.

I have Googled a lot, but all I could find was how to add a signature image in the pdf. Does Apple provide any libraries for digital signature?

Comment: Sure, it's all in the Security.framework (CommonCrypto)

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. Will check it out and get back to you..

Comment: @borrrden CommonCrypto offers only basic security. PDF signing as per PDF standard (where the signature is embedded into the document) is not supported in CommonCrypto, is it?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I am unaware of this form of signing.  No you cannot embed it in the document, but I don't see anything in the original question that implies it.  I was thinking just a normal digital signature (without embedding)

Comment: @borrrden Which one do you call "normal"? Wrapping, embedded, detached?  PDF format specifies the rules of how to sign the document and have it shown correctly with the signatures indicated and validated by the reader.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I meant normal as in the digital signature that is common to the security world outside of PDFs.  Just the digital signature, with no specification on how it is transferred.

Comment: @borrrden there's no such thing as "normal", sorry. The term is too broad to identify something particular. As I asked, which of wrapping, embedded, detached do you consider "normal"?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Why do I need to choose?  Those terms don't seem to apply to the signature itself, but how it is provided along with the data.  OP asked "Does Apple provide any libraries for digital signature?" so I answered (admittedly being unaware that the PDF standard supplies its own rules about how they are transmitted).  So really to me a digital signature is just a set of bytes that can authenticate a given document (whether they are embedded in the document, passed separately, whatever...)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you also need to understand and discuss (with the right business person) the security of the digital certificate(s) used for signing.

If you want to ensure that no one/nothing except for authorized people and processes will be able to sign with the certificate, then the certificate must be stored in a secure hardware device.

The two common secure signing system types are smart cards and signing servers. Smart cards can be difficult to interface to. Signing servers are easy to use via network APIs. [Example signing server APIs](http://developer.arx.com). Signing servers are available as web services if you want.